# R arules - subset of transactions that match a rule

Tags: r, subset, arules

I'm using the R package [arules](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html). I have some transactions and a rule (see below). I want the subset of transactions that *break* the rule. How can I do that?

This is the set up:

```
library(arules)
data(Adult)
summary(Adult)
rules = apriori(Adult,parameter=list(support=0.2,confidence=0.8))
summary(rules)
r=rules[1]
```

I want the subset of transactions that contain the left hand side of the rule `r` but not the right hand side.  The arules documentation doesn't have an example like this. I've tried `%in%`, `match` and `subset` but I can't get the syntax right.

The documentation for the `subset` function has an example of subsetting rules, but no examples of subsetting transactions.

http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/subset.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the package in question, but have you tried investigating your object with `str()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the subset syntax in the context of arules is very similar to any other context: you may want to try the following:

```
subset(transactions, items %in% lhs(r) & !items %in% rhs(r) )
```

I hope this helps!